# How to setup multi-tenant row-level security with groups in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here below I'm trying to setup row-level security for table `my_resources`... where each record belongs to a specific tenant and subject. Furthermore, anybody who belongs to at least one of the groups in `acl_groups_read` can access the record in read-only:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_resources(
    ...

    acl_tenant_read     UUID[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('tenant')]::uuid[] NOT NULL,
    acl_tenant_write    UUID[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('tenant')]::uuid[] NOT NULL,
    acl_sub_read        UUID[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('subject')]::uuid[] NOT NULL,
    acl_sub_write       UUID[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('subject')]::uuid[] NOT NULL,
    acl_groups_read     VARCHAR(255)[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('groups')]::varchar[] NOT NULL,
    acl_groups_write    VARCHAR(255)[] DEFAULT array[current_setting('groups')]::varchar[] NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_tenant_read);
CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_tenant_write);
CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_sub_read);
CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_sub_write);
CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_groups_read);
CREATE INDEX ON my_resources USING gin(acl_groups_write);


CREATE POLICY my_resources_policy ON my_resources
USING ((
    acl_tenant_read @> array[current_setting('tenant')]::uuid[]
    OR
    acl_tenant_write @> array[current_setting('tenant')]::uuid[]
) AND (
    acl_sub_read @> array[current_setting('subject')]::uuid[]
    OR
    acl_sub_write @> array[current_setting('subject')]::uuid[]
    OR
    acl_groups_read @> array[current_setting('groups')]::varchar[]
    OR
    acl_groups_write @> array[current_setting('groups')]::varchar[]
))
WITH CHECK ((
    acl_tenant_write @> array[current_setting('tenant')]::uuid[]
) AND (
    acl_sub_write @> array[current_setting('subject')]::uuid[]
    OR
    acl_groups_write @> array[current_setting('groups')]::varchar[]
));

ALTER TABLE my_resources ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

When creating a transaction, I set the user of the current SQL session to be a given role:

```
SET LOCAL myRole TO 'currentUser'
```

How do I let row-level securitiy also consider `tenant` and `groups`?

Comment: How does one belong to multiple groups?

Comment: Does your rls policy not already consider `tenant` just fine? Which part of it works, which doesn't?

Comment: @Bergi When creating a new record, `groups` just contains one group named like the subject (i.e. only the creator has RW access to the record). The idea would be to create a function that let me add groups like `admin`, `deputy`, etc. to `acl_groups_*`.

Comment: Yeah, but `current_setting('groups')` will always contain only a single group?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I think `tenant` should be fine... my doubt was what happens when I run a query from a function in my code... is `SET LOCAL myRole TO 'currentUser'` enough, or shall I also set somehow `tenant` and`groups` to let RLS work as expected? I was unable to find a comprehensive example :-(

Comment: `groups` might contain one or more groups

Comment: Yes, you must set all three settings. [`current_setting('…')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) throws an error otherwise. If you don't want to do that, you can use `current_setting('…', true)` to get back `NULL`, and ignore it then or `COALESCE` it to a default value or something.

Comment: If it contains multiple groups, I doubt `acl_groups_write @> array[current_setting('groups')]` works. I had expected something like `acl_groups_write && string_to_array(current_setting('groups'), '|')` (or whatever delimiter you'd use).

Comment: Ah OK I see, I need to add `SET LOCAL "tenant" TO 'myTenant'` in my client code... but what's about the `groups`?

Comment: Same there. Notice that settings must be strings, so if there's multiple groups you'll need to find  way to serialise them.

Comment: @Bergi OK thank u very much for your valuable support!